# "Binary type has different field types" Error when using Date type field in Key or Value

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I am trying to use `java.util.Date` type field in my Ignite Key and Value objects. But when I start caching data in same Ignite cache using Java code, I get following error.

```
[12:43:01,485][SEVERE][pool-8-thread-1][] Message is ignored due to an error [msg=MessageAndMetadata(test1,2,Message(magic = 1, attributes = 0, CreateTime = -1, crc = 3705259101, key = java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=4 cap=3288], payload = java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=3280 cap=3280]),302,kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder@2d50c6a2,kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder@1ff7596c,-1,CreateTime)]
class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Binary type has different field types [typeName=test.demo.DataKey, fieldName=tstamp, fieldTypeName1=String, fieldTypeName2=Date]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.mergeMetadata(BinaryUtils.java:1027)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.binary.BinaryMetadataTransport$MetadataUpdateProposedListener.onCustomEvent(BinaryMetadataTransport.java:293)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.binary.BinaryMetadataTransport$MetadataUpdateProposedListener.onCustomEvent(BinaryMetadataTransport.java:258)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$4.onDiscovery0(GridDiscoveryManager.java:707)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$4.onDiscovery(GridDiscoveryManager.java:589)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.notifyDiscoveryListener(ServerImpl.java:5479)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processCustomMessage(ServerImpl.java:5305)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processMessage(ServerImpl.java:2765)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processMessage(ServerImpl.java:2536)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorkerAdapter.body(ServerImpl.java:6775)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:2621)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
```

Where `DataKey` is Ignite cache Key which is defined as follows,

```
package test.demo;
import java.util.Date;

public class DataKey{

    private Long sess_id ;                                                                                  
    private Long   s_id;                                                                    
    private Long   version;                                                                     
    private Date tstamp;


    public DataKey(Long sess_id, Long s_id, Long version,
            Date tstamp) {
        super();
        this.sess_id = sess_id;
        this.s_id = s_id;
        this.version = version;
        this.tstamp = tstamp;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((s_id == null) ? 0 : s_id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((sess_id == null) ? 0 : sess_id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((tstamp == null) ? 0 : tstamp.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((version == null) ? 0 : version.hashCode());
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        DataKey other = (DataKey) obj;
        if (s_id == null) {
            if (other.s_id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!s_id.equals(other.s_id))
            return false;
        if (sess_id == null) {
            if (other.sess_id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!sess_id.equals(other.sess_id))
            return false;
        if (tstamp == null) {
            if (other.tstamp != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!tstamp.equals(other.tstamp))
            return false;
        if (version == null) {
            if (other.version != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!version.equals(other.version))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

As mentioned in link http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Binary-type-has-different-fields-error-td21540.html , I even deleted contents from `$IGNITE_HOME/work/` directory and restarted the node. But still error is there.
What is causing this error? Also same error occurs if `java.util.Date` type field is only used in cache value(not in key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in `ignitevisor`. I have used `Node Singleton` service deployment mode of Ignite, in which application is deployed on each Ignite instance in cluster. At same time configuration was also getting applied to `ignitevisor`. Now during next run `ignitevisor` was `ON` with old configuration. So when I deployed new application on cluster using `Node Singleton` service deployment mode, there was conflict between old and new `<key, value>` object types, as `ignitevisor` was holding old configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have other nodes running which have old version of code deployed where `timestamp` is `String`?

Note that in your snippet it is `tstamp` but in the error message it is `timestamp`. Any chance there is some random confusion? Clear it, remove `work/` on all nodes, and try again.

Comment: I have renamed fields while posting Key class here that is why there is mismatch of names in Key class and error logs. Now I have corrected it in error logs. There is no other node running with `string` data type of field, only one is running with `Date` type. I have also tried removing `$IGNITE_HOME/work/` from nodes, but still error is present.